# PHP mail() - change sender email address

Tags: php, email, sender

My site is host by proserwer.pl. When I try send mail to gmail.com like that:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: "Admin My-Site.PL" <admin@my_site.pl>'."\n";
        $topic = $lang['Active_Account_Email'];
        $topic = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($topic) . '?=';
        $message = 'message';
        if ( mail($email, $topic, $message, $headers) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
```

My sent email always is in SPAM. The problem is **sender email**: 66.proserwer@proserwer.pl
How I can change this email?

Comment: Which type of mail server you are using? you can change it from mail server setting.

Comment: Ask your web hosting company about SPF and DKIM, and make sure both are set up for your domain.

Comment: 'From: Admin My-Site.PL <admin@my_site.pl>'."\r\n";

Comment: Hmm, I don't know where I can check this type. I'm using Cpanel. I don't have access to edit php.ini etc. Can I change it in php code?

Comment: @JoniSalmi 'From' isn't the same as 'sender'.

Comment: It would help if you provided the email headers on the received message. "The problem is sender email" - how do you know that?

Comment: Because much people is using mail() function on this hosting and much people send spam. Gmail saved this email ('66.proserwer@proserwer.pl') on spam-list. I think, here is problem.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I found in CPanel "Email Authentication" and I enable DKIM but I don't know how I can add my sender email :/